# Powershell tests in TravisCI fail due to missing RequiredModules

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, travis-ci, pester, import-module

I'm playing with `powershell` and run my test locally and on TravisCI.

#### Module Manifest

```
RequiredModules = @('ClipboardText')
```

#### Travis Config

Currently I install `powershell` and [`pester`](https://github.com/pester/Pester) before running my tests

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - sourceline: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod trusty main
        key_url: https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
    packages:
      - powershell
      - xclip
before_script:
  - pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name Pester -Force -Scope CurrentUser'
script:
  - make test
```

#### Makefile

```
test:
    pwsh -Command 'Get-childItem -Recurse *.test.ps1 | foreach { Invoke-Pester -EnableExit $$_ }'
```

#### Travis Build

[Build](https://github.com/pester/Pester) throws error:

```bsh
Import-Module : The required module 'ClipboardText' is not loaded. 
Load the module or remove the module from 'RequiredModules' in the file '/home/travis/build/edouard-lopez/lesspass-powershell/lesspass.psd1'.
At /home/travis/build/edouard-lopez/lesspass-powershell/Clipboard.test.ps1:1 char:1
+ Import-Module $PSScriptRoot/lesspass.psd1 -Force  # force code to be  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (/home/travis/bu...l/lesspass.psd1:String) [Import-Module], MissingMemberException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

#### Question

I thought that declaring `RequiredModules` would install `ClipboardText` thus allowing my test to be executed correctly.
If I manually install the module `ClipboardText` locally my test works, but is it the right thing to do on CI and future distribution of my module?

Comment: It will load the module, but not install it. Is it already installed on the machine? And if yes, check the module's installation path. It should be at a global location that applies to all users.

Answer (score 2):

Per the other answer, the `RequiredModules` field of a module manifest defines any modules that must be imported into the global environment, prior to importing this module.

These modules must therefore already be installed on the system, but do not need to be loaded (imported) in to the current session.

As a result in order to ensure your tests work on the CI system you would need to ensure that your test script performed an install of the required modules (e.g via `Install-Module` if they are available in the PSGallery or other nuget repo).

If it is possible to test your script without the dependent module, you could write Pester scripts that work around the issue by Mocking the required functions without the module needing to be present. This can be done by defining empty functions for the cmdlets that are missing and then (optionally) declaring mocks for them so that you can validate that they have been invoked as expected:

```
. YourModule.psm1

Function Some-Function { }

Mock Some-Function { }

Describe 'Testing Invoke-SomeCmdlet invokes Some-Function as part of its code' {

    $Result = Invoke-SomeCmdlet

    It 'Should invoke Some-Function' {
        Assert-MockCalled Some-Function
    }
}
```

Without declaring the cmdlet as an empty `Function` the `Mock` would fail as you can only mock a cmdlet/function that exists.

Note that in order to test your code this way you'd need to load the code without invoking the Module manifest (e.g dot source the .ps1 or .psm1 file/s directly vs loading the module via the .psd1, otherwise the `RequiredModules` statement would cause the test script to fail).

Obviously its simpler to just have any required modules present, but sometimes that might not always be possible, the above is just to demonstrate how you can workaround such a scenario.

Answer (score 2):

As described by [Mark Wragg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348884/802365) and [Dejulia489](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337223/802365) answers, you **need to install the module before importing** it.

#### [*.travis.yml*](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/lesspass-powershell/blob/41996238d77f519620fd566d694ad27c00fe868d/.travis.yml#L16)

Add `ClipboardText` to the list of modules to install:

```
before_script:
 - pwsh -Command 'Install-Module -Name Pester,ClipboardText -Force -Scope CurrentUser'
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell required modules must be loaded into the global environment prior to importing the root module. - [Powershell Module Manifest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest)

> Modules that must be imported into the global environment prior to importing this module
> RequiredModules = @()

Confirm that 'ClipboardText' is installed in one of the paths listed in $Env:PSModulePath. You can do this by opening a powershell session on the Travis Build server and running

```
Import-Module 'ClipboardText'
```

If this fails you will need to install the clipboardtest module correctly.